# What is the errorCode of MAT_DATEPICKER_VALIDATORS?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `MAT_DATEPICKER_VALIDATORS` for my form validation.

```js
primaryFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  deadline: [null, MAT_DATEPICKER_VALIDATORS],
});
```

I would like to display a text to this error message.

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="primaryFormGroup.get('deadline').errors">Date is not valid</mat-error>
```

This will work but it's not the best solution, since there will be other validations and each error should have its own text.

I would like to use it that way:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="primaryFormGroup.get('deadline').hasError('')">Date is not valid</mat-error>
```

but what exactly is the errorCode (the first parameter of `hasError()`) of `MAT_DATEPICKER_VALIDATORS`?

Comment: try write in your .html `{{primaryFormGroup.get('deadline').errors|json}}`. You can see then an object,  Seeing the fonts https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts, The object can be the properties, `matDatepickerParse`, `matDatepickerMin`, `matDatepickerMax` and `matDatepickerFilter`. So, you can ask about, e.g. primaryFormGroup.get('deadline').errors?.matDatePickerParse

Comment: @Eliseo thank you, that helped me a lot! The errorCode is: **matDatepickerParse**

Comment: be carefully, you can has differents errors, e.g. if you use [max] or [min], the error object can change. It's like you create a input with the validators Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]. The error can be one or severals among: {required:true} or {minlength: {requiredLength: 3, actualLength: 2}} or {pattern: {requiredPattern: '^[a-zA-Z ]*$', actualValue: '1'}}